# sed multiline search-replace

Tags: regex, sed, replace, multiline

I got fortran code of nasty old syntax and want to port to new syntax.
My **`sed` command**

```
sed -nr 'N;s/\n\s*\d\D\s*//g' file
```

should find numbered line breaks, but doesn't work for a reason I don't know. I already had a look in numberous multiline-`sed` questions here and I still can't fid my misunderstanding. From my understanding the command works like this:

```
N                   append next line to pattern space; thus pattern space has two lines with \n in between
s///g               usual search-replace
\n\s*\d\D\s*        matches a newline followed by \s*, a digit, a non-digit and a \s* again
```

The **source code** looks like

```
   if(condition) then 
         call func1(v1, v2, v3, v4
     1              ,v5,v6,v7)
      else
         call func2(v1, v2, v3, v4
     1              ,v5,v6,v7)
      endif
call MPI_BCAST(num(1),1,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION
     1     ,masterid,comm,mpinfo)
21      format(' text',2x,f10.5)
```

and should transform to the **target code**

```
   if(condition) then 
         call func1(v1, v2, v3, v4,v5,v6,v7)
      else
         call func2(v1, v2, v3, v4,v5,v6,v7)
      endif
call MPI_BCAST(num(1),1,MPI_DOUBLE_PRECISION,masterid,comm,mpinfo)
21      format(' text',2x,f10.5)
```

Comment: sed doesn't support `\d` or `\D`.. `\s` is supported by `GNU sed` (not sure about other implementations)... also, using `N` (without additional workaround commands) will prevent you from using that line again.. for ex, first two lines are paired, so you'll never be able to match the 3rd line which is what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E ':a;N;s/\n\s*[0-9]\s*([^0-9])/\1/;ta;P;D' file
```

Traverse through the file using a 2 line window.

If the second line starts with some or no white space, followed by a digit, followed by some more or no white space, followed by a non-digit, replace this by the non-digit and repeat. Otherwise print the first line of the window, then delete it and repeat.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works for me! But I am a bit confused regarding @Sundeep 's comment. If sed with the command `N` reads in the file in joint lines 12, 34, 56, ... instead of 12, 23, 34, ... then I don't see how the above command could match linebreak in 23, 45, ... But obviously it does?!

Comment: The `D` command is special in that it not only deletes up to and including the first newline in the pattern space, but if the pattern space is not then empty it suppresses the implicit reading of the next line and instead jumps to the first command in the sed cycle. Thus if there were 2 lines in the pattern space the second becomes the first.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. I think I got it!

Answer (score 1):

Here's one possible solution with `perl` that works for given sample input:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\n\h*\d\h*(?=,)//g'
```

- `-0777` slurp entire input as single string
- `\n\h*\d\h*` match newline character followed by optional horizontal spaces followed by a digit character followed by optional horizontal spaces

  - `(?=,)` match only if there's a comma character after such a match... otherwise, you'll need to tell how to NOT match `21      format(' text',2x,f10.5)`

With `GNU sed`, but my understanding of these commands isn't good enough to be confident:

```
sed -E 'N; s/\n\s*[0-9]\s*,/,/; P; D'
```

From [GNU sed manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Other-Commands):

> **P** Print out the portion of the pattern space up to the first newline.

> **D** If pattern space contains no newline, start a normal new cycle as if the d command was issued. Otherwise, delete text in the pattern space up to the first newline, and restart cycle with the resultant pattern space, without reading a new line of input.

Comment: Your `perl` solution works like a charm! Also your `sed` example helped me better understand the mechanic behind it. But before diving into `perl` I try to stick to `sed` although I believe perl is much simpler in many situations.